# Return an Array Length in Livecode

Tags: arrays, livecode, variable-length-array

I have an array with four string values "Hello","All","of", and "you". I need to display the total length of the array which is 4 and display it to label text. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

"item 2 of the extents of YourArrayName" will show you the last element number, which is in some cases the length of an array. item 1 will shoe you the first element number.  Elements are sometimes also called indexes. MyArray[1],MyArray[2] etc.

or

put the number of elements of MyArrayName into field "Array Length"

or

put the number of lines of the keys of MyArrayName into field ""Array Length"

Comment: For checking the length of the array you should use `the number of elements of MyArrayName` form.

Also, you can't check `the number of keys` an array. You would need to check `the number of lines of the keys`.

Comment: yes thats right. Will edit answer! Thanks for correction